# Java program skips over System.out.println() - maybe JSch related?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm running a test case using testng. This testcase uses Jsch to try to send a ssh command to a remote machine. The Jsch function is supposed to return output from command (including any exceptions). However, I can't view the output and the test passes, even when there's been an timeout exception!

Here's the JSch function:

```
public static String sshCommand (String username, String password, String host, int port, String command) {
    StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        System.out.println("about to send command: " + command);
        JSch jschSSHChannel = new JSch();
        Session session=jschSSHChannel.getSession(username, host, port);

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();          
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();

        while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
        {
            outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
            readByte = commandOutput.read();
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception encountered returning: " + e.toString());
        return e.toString();
    }

    return outputBuffer.toString();
}
```

Here's the code that evaluates the output from the ssh function:

```
String output = jschClass.sshCommand("username", "password", ipAddress, 22, command);
System.out.println("Command output: " + output);
Assert.assertTrue(!output.contains("Exception"));
System.out.println("Test complete");
```

The problem is I never see the `System.out.println("Command output: " + output);` printed. It skips right over that statement and executes `System.out.println("Test complete");` before exiting.

Additionally, the catch statement I put in the sshcommand function never seems to execute. An exception is displayed, but it doesn't seem to be executing the code I wrote. In fact it's almost like the exception is coming from somewhere else. Here's what I see in the program's output:

```
about to send command: ping -c 5 google.com
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Test complete
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at com.cisco.ui2.openstack.jsch.JschHelper.sshCommand(JschHelper.java:28)
at com.cisco.ui2.openstack.PingPublicSite.createImageAndPingPublicSite(PingPublicSite.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[removed for space]
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
... 28 more
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This is why we use logger and not sysout.

Comment: Seems a bit weird, because based on the code, you should havenothing after "Test Complete", but you still have the stacktrace.

Comment: channel.connect(); probably has it's own catch block, causing yours to never be reached. Why your print statement is not working is beyond me, it is probably due to the thrown bock. Use a proper logger and see how that goes, generally you should not use system.print for logging, if you want to see if code is being reached, add conditional break points.

Comment: Are you sure you running the same code you're looking at? another version perhaps, or IDE is not compiling - eclipse - check "build automatically" option... Also, try adding a breakpoint on the "command output" line and using the debugger...

Comment: @Zsolt Yeah, that's another weird thing. The stack trace is printing after "Test complete" but the first line of it appears before "Test complete".

I can add logging statements and retry.